# I am trying to write GraphQL schema for the first time for creating an API for my project but I am getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am trying to write a Graphql schema for creating API.
Here is the GraphQL schema :

```
input AMPLIFY { globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public } } # FOR TESTING ONLY!

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName:"byUser", fields: ["id"])

}

type Post @model @key( name: "byUser",fields: ["userID"] ){
  id: ID!
  videoUri: String!
  description:String!
  userID: ID!
  user: User @connection(fields:["userID"])
  songID: ID!
  song:Song @connection(fields:["songID"]) 
  }

type Song @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String!
}
```

I am trying to write a GraphQL schema for creating an API for my project and later after doing **amplify push** in my terminal I am getting this error "`Your GraphQL Schema is using "@connection", "@key" directives from an older version of the GraphQL Transformer.`"
and after doing amplify console api  I am getting this error on the AWS amplify console.

[image: 1]

Please correct me where I am wrong as I am new to GraphQL and AWS. Thanks